# Gulp-sass how to change dest output

Tags: gulp, shopify, gulp-sass

I'm trying to set a shopify dev workflow, and i'm stuck in a problem. How can i change the dest() output in gulp-sass to use .liquid files in the assets folder?

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  gulp.src('stylesheets/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/'));
});
```

I want to get as output something like `main.css.liquid`, so i can use the .liquid methods.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a good thread about it @ [Gulp](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/34). As said it seems that [gulp-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename) may be a great fit.

In your case, you can change your code to:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    gulp.src('stylesheets/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.rename('destinationpath/yourfile.liquid'));
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/'));
});
```

Comment: thanks man! i've already solved and forgot to put the answer here, but that's pretty much the solution! I added gulp-rename and add it to  the sass task a bit different than you did. :)

`.pipe(rename({ suffix: '.css', extname: '.liquid' }))`
obrigado!